# Find ALL given characters are present in a string. Characters can be present anywhere in the string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to find whether the given characters are present in the string or not.

For the below example, it returns true. But it should be false since there is only one 'a' in 'abcdef'.

My Requirement:

1. Confirm all the given characters are present in the string.
2. Characters can be anywhere in the string. No need they should be in the same order. But the count is important. In the below example, I have given 'aca', which contains two 'a' but the value in regex contains only one 'a' in 'abcdef'.

How to check all given characters are present in the string or not?

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^[abcdef]+$");
regEx.test('aca') // returns true. **Expected**: false for this case
```

Comment: Why regex? Just loop over the characters that should be in the string and test with `.indexOf()`. Or use `Array.prototype.every()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find the count of each character and then use [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to check if all the characters are present.

```js
function findAll(str, key) {
  let count = str.split('').reduce((count, c) => {
    count[c] = count[c] + 1 || 1;
    return count;
  }, {});

  return key.split('').every(c => {
    if (count[c]) {
      count[c]--;
      return true;
    }
  });
}

console.log(findAll("abcdef", "abc"));
console.log(findAll("abcdef", "abca"));
console.log(findAll("abcdef", "xyz"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Short *trick* with regexp matching and `Set` object:

```js
var chars = 'abcdef'

function match_all(str, char_str){
    var pat = RegExp('['+ char_str +']', 'g'),
   matched_chars = [...new Set(str.match(pat))];
    matched_chars.sort()
    console.log(matched_chars.join('') == char_str)
}
  
match_all('aca', chars)
match_all('acbacadaef1a2a3', chars)
match_all('ccbacad1e2d', chars)
```